# In PHP,How to wrap my own is_empty function?

Tags: php

I tried to wrap my own function using `empty()`.
The function named `is_empty` is to check whether a value is empty, if it's empty, return a specified value. Code is as below.

```
static public function is_empty($val,$IfEmptyThenReturnValue)
    {
        if(empty($val))
        {
            return $IfEmptyThenReturnValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return $val;
        }
    }
```

And I call this function like this:

```
$d="it's a value";
echo  Common::is_empty($d, "null");
```

That's ok. It printed the "it's a value".

but if I don't defined the `$d`. like below:

```
echo  Common::is_empty($d, "null");
```

Yes, it will print the "null".
But it will also print a `waring:Notice`:

```
 Undefined variable: d in D:\phpwwwroot\test1.php on line 25.
```

So how to fix this function?

Comment: Use `isset()` in your function

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. When you pass the value into your method, you already trigger the notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `&` to save your life:

```
class Common{
    static public function is_empty(&$val,$IfEmptyThenReturnValue){
        if(empty($val)){
            return $IfEmptyThenReturnValue;
        }else{
            return $val;
        }
    }
}

echo Common::is_empty($d,"null");
```

Comment: This will also set the variables in addition to returning their values  though.

Comment: meaning if the variable isn't set, then it will be. a win win for everyone

Comment: Oh, yes ,I should remember to use the reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by passing in the name of the variable rather than the variable itself, and then utilising variable variables in the function:

```
static public function is_empty($var, $IfEmptyThenReturnValue)
{
    if(empty($$var))
    {
        return $IfEmptyThenReturnValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return $$var;
    }
} 

echo Common::is_empty('d', 'null');
```

However, instead having a function for this in the first place I would just do:

```
echo empty($d) ? 'null' : $d;
```